# Operations with long number in web

Tags: php, javascript, perl, math

I'd like to write (not to use existing one) a library (or something) that works with long numbers (I mean at least few hundred digits).

The first question: choosing a language for it. Which one is better: Perl/JavaScript/PHP?

The second question: how to implement operations with long numbers? The only thing I get is to work with them as with arrays, e.g.:

```
arr1 = (12, 34); //1234
arr2 = (98, 76); //9876
sum = longnumbers_add(arr1, arr2); // +
// 34 + 76 = 110 = 10 -..> 1
// 12 + 98 = 110 = 110 + 1 = 11 -..> 1
//sum == (1, 11, 10);
```

But it worked to slow (at least with my try in PHP). Maybe there's some "shift bits" super-fast method?

**P.S.**

I know there are gmp and other cool libraries.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use strings for representation. And no, there is no magic shift bits method. It will be slow. This is a flawed implementation approach if speed is an issue.

Comment: @mario can you please tell more about representing number as a string? should i split the string, make some operations and concatenate them then? I would be thankfull for a small example.

Comment: @ted It will be better if you represent number as string instead of array. As it will be easier to read. instead of `Array(12,90)` `"1290"` will be more readable.  Also are you passing argument to function by reference as it will increase speed considerably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a couple big number libraries for fun. As far as the language, I would either choose whichever one you're most comfortable with or one you want to learn more about. For me, that was JavaScript most recently, but in my opinion, none of those languages are any more or less suited to large numbers. For the web though, a large part of the decision comes down to whether you want to do the calculations on the client or server side. On the client side, JavaScript is pretty much the only option.

I wrote a couple blog posts demonstrating the basic algorithms and how I chose to store them. Note that these are for big integers only (so no decimal point), but the basics still apply.

- http://silentmatt.com/blog/2011/10/how-bigintegers-work/
- http://silentmatt.com/blog/2011/10/how-bigintegers-work-part-2-multiplication/

Here are a few thoughts from my experience:

- It's probably easiest conceptually to store the numbers in base 10 because it's more familiar, but it really doesn't change much of the implementation. Larger bases are more efficient though (in both memory and speed).
- It's almost always simpler to keep the digits in "little endian" order, so the least significant digit comes first in the array (or if you used strings, store them reversed).
- Don't worry too much about performance until you get it working. The fastest way to do things can sometimes be surprising so you'll get it wrong anyway, and it's easy to go back and optimize each operation once you're done.
- If you want to support decimals, it can be easiest to write an integer type first, then implement floating point numbers on top of that. Basically, you can separate out the code to keep track of decimal places so it keeps the algorithms cleaner.
- You'll need to decide if you want to use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (10's complement, or the equivalent for whatever base you choose also works) or sign-magnitude (where you store the sign separately from the digits) for handling negative numbers. Each method is more complicated in some areas and simpler in others. Generally though, n's-complement is probably simpler if you have a fixed size, but sign-magnitude might be simpler for arbitrarily-sized numbers.

Comment: So, i keep numbers in decimal, they are "little endian", i also put 4 digits per array's cell(i thought that would improve performance a little), no floating point numbers are needed, i prefer sign-magnitude. Now i have issues with longnumber_module (`%` i mean)  implemention; it's pretty slow as i try to do that like: number - coefficient * mod, where coefficient =(approximatly) number / mod; I also have no idea how to generate long_number primes. Rabin-miller test wouldn't be the best decision i guess? Is there any way i can communicate with you to get some tips(may be your blog?).Thank you.

Comment: @ted Oops, I thought I replied to this already... I've always combined modulus/remainder and division into one function, since it's easy to keep track of the remainder as you divide. Then the division function would just return the quotient. Rabin-miller should be fine for testing/generating primes. You can email me if you want (or ask specific questions here). There's a contact form on  my website: http://silentmatt.com/contact/.

Comment: It would be great to see **division** (and module as a part of it) at your blog. To tell the truth i should be pretty 'talanted' because your multiplication with O(n^2) works faster than my implementation of Kurutsuba longnumber multiplication.

Comment: @ted Yeah, I'm planning on writing about division, but I haven't gotten around to it yet. I actually had the same issue with multiplication, which is why I'm using the O(n^2) algorithm (for now at least. I might re-evaluate it later). One thing that might help is increasing the number of digits in each cell. You can go up to 7 digits without running into precision problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you want to write a high-level library for working with long numbers (e.g. for calculating primes or something) or just implement the low-level operations (addition, multiplication) for learning purposes. If you're interested in the former, you should consider Python instead of JavaScript/PHP/Perl. Python has builtin-support for arbitrarily large integers and a decimal class for exact floating point arithmetic in its standard library.

Comment: Yes, "that" should be used for generating primes, finding matrix's determinant and so on;

Answer (score -2):

You should try BCMath: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: `not to use existing library`

Comment: Out of the bounds of the question asked.